# QField always records duplicate points

Tags: qfield, duplicates

Every time I save a point in Qfield, it creates two with consecutive numbering that differ in the options I have marked. The first point is as I want but in the second point the options marked when I fill in the data entry form are not registered.

I have checked again and it keeps happening to me both in the Qfield desktop application and in the APK but if I insert a point in Qgis, it only records one, no more. I don't know what's going on.

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Previously it worked properly for me. I use QGIS v 3.28.3 and QField v4.4.9.

Comment: Have you tried to upload again the same project? Moreover, are you using QFieldCloud or the cable transfer?